# LVM space suddenly gone

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm having issues with LVM on a Debian Jessie server. After adding a new SSD to the group **storage** I extended the volume, no issues were seen. After a power outage though, the server went offline for a bit. Eventually it came back up. That's when I noticed that there was a lot of space missing. According to df, there's only 50GB. I feel there is something I'm missing.

Any ideas?

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0                 106G  102G     0 100% /
udev                       10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     1.4G  9.7M  1.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                     3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                     3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 236M   36M  188M  16% /boot
/dev/mapper/storage-stor   50G   50G     0 100% /storage_share
tmpfs                     695M     0  695M   0% /run/user/1000
```

---

**vgs**

```
VG             #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
home-server-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 111.55g     0
storage          3   1   0 wz--n- 400.56g 97.66g
```

---

**pvs**

```
  PV         VG             Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda5  home-server-vg lvm2 a--  111.55g     0
  /dev/sdb1  storage        lvm2 a--  111.79g     0
  /dev/sdc1  storage        lvm2 a--   55.89g 55.89g
  /dev/sdd1  storage        lvm2 a--  232.88g 41.77g
```

---

**lvs**

```
LV     VG             Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   home-server-vg -wi-ao---- 106.98g
  swap_1 home-server-vg -wi-ao----   4.56g
  stor   storage        -wi-ao---- 302.90g
```

---

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc99fa34a

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 234441647 234439600 111.8G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdd: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe95e10c9

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 488397167 488395120 232.9G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 55.9 GiB, 60022480896 bytes, 117231408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb18e3326

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 117231407 117229360 55.9G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xedbe0f11

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 234440703 233938946 111.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 234440703 233938944 111.6G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/home--server--vg-root: 107 GiB, 114873597952 bytes, 224362496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/home--server--vg-swap_1: 4.6 GiB, 4898947072 bytes, 9568256     sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/storage-stor: 302.9 GiB, 325238915072 bytes, 635232256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You /dev/sdb1, sdc1 and sdd1 partition does not have the correct partition type. It's listed as 'Linux', so the kernel will expect a regular filesystem there. /dev/sda5 is of type LVM which used for your root file system, I guess (BTW, time to clean that partition up...)

I guess it worked before because the kernel, while scanning the disks for LVM signatures, found one on the first disk. Adding a disk changed the order in which the disks are scanned but the problem only becomes evident after the first reboot because then there is something on the new disk. I think that by sheer accident your superblock is located at the beginning of /dev/sdc1 and the kernel goes "Hey, that's a filesystem. Good, let's mount that.", ignoring the rest.

I think you also may have to rebuild your LVM after fixing this, because your filesystem is now most likely corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What do you suggest is the best way to handle this? (in order to minimize data loss)

Comment: Not sure... It will be difficult to get the pieces of your LVM back into the correct order and get a filesystem that is somehow readable. I suggest you copy the 50 GB that you have access to now to an external resource (harddisk, FTP or rsync to remote host). Then rebuild the LVM properly and copy the data back. Trying to piece it back together is probably more trouble than it's worth.